# setting marker to location from string android-google-maps-api

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, maps

I have a map and I want to be able add in a location from a string and have it add a marker on that location. so far I have some code that that I thought might work but i keep getting errors. I will post the code.

**First Activity**

```
LON = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.LON);
LAT = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.LAT);
SL  = (Button)   findViewById (R.id.SL);

SL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent (SetLocation.this,GarageSellerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("lonstring", LON.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("latstring", LAT.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

The first activity has no errors and works as far as going to the next activity.

**Second Activity**

```
private String          LONString;
private String          LATString;

//**Turns longitude EditText into a string**\\
LONString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lonstring", "");
//**Turns latitude EditText into a string.**\\
LATString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("latstring", "");

GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(LONString,+LATString);
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");

itemizedoverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
mapOverlays2.add(itemizedoverlay1);'
```

I have errors on both .getString and on LONString and LATString inside the geopoints. Any help is appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Qiu, It says "The constructor GeoPoint(string,string) is undifined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass Longitude and Latitude as Integers, not Strings. Just convert them when you pass them to GeoPoint. Like this:

```
GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(Integer.parseInt(LONString), Integer.parseInt(LATString));
```

You might want to do some filtering in your input as well to make sure they're not passing anything nasty.

Comment: That gets rid of the errors, but I keep getting a force close on `LONString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lonstring")` and `LATString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("latstring")` any suggestions?

Comment: I could help if I knew the reason of the close. Null pointer exception probably? Check your LogCat window.

Comment: I would like to give you the log cat, but I can't even get the application to run with this problem.

Comment: Well try adding a `this` to before `getIntent()`. Check to make sure your scope is correct.  
`LONString = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("lonstring", "");`